# An esay way to empty a config file in Linux?

Tags: linux, vim, nano

Is there a way to empty a configuration file in Linux without deleting it so that it won't lose the permissions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cat /dev/null > file.txt
```

Executing this command will make the file blank.

Comment: Or just `> file.txt`. Shorter, but also will empty the file.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is

```
printf '' > file
```

The `>file` trick has a slightly different behaviour depending on the used shell. In `zsh` for instance, it's required to terminate the redirection with <kbd>ctrl-d</kbd> if `NULLCMD` is set to `cat` (which is the default).

Comment: To make `> file` work as in `bash` you simply need to set `NULLCMD=:`. The default is `NULLCMD=cat`, so `> file` is identical to `cat > file` which needs to be terminated by `EOF`, i.e. `CTRL+D`.